# Objective C subclass that overrides a method in the superclass

Tags: objective-c, overriding, subclass

In Objective C, if you are subclassing something, and are planning to override a method on the superclass, should you re-declare the superclass method in your subclass @interface?

For example, if you are subclassing UIViewController (e.g. MyViewController), and you are planning to override "viewDidLoad" should you include that method in your MyViewController @interface declaration, or just implement it in MyViewController.m?

In examples I've come across, I've seen it done both ways (re-declaring the method in your subclass interface, or not re-declaring the method).  There may not be any functional difference, but what is the best practice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I often declare methods that I plan to override in either the public header or at least in a private category. The benefit to this is that you'll get an incomplete class definition warning if you forget to actually override the method... which comes in handy from time to time.

As for **when** to place it in the public header, that's pretty subjective and probably up to you/your team's coding styles. I usually only redeclare a method in the public header if I plan to radically change what the method is going to do or if I plan not to invoke the super class's version of the method.

Comment: +1 That makes sense.  Someone with a name like "Coco(a)" must know what he's doing.

Comment: You get an incomplete definition warning even though the superclass has an implementation? I didn't know that; always thought that declaring a method already present in the superclass was redundant, whether you override it or not.

Comment: @ranReloaded You only get the warning if you specifically re-declare the method. Basically, when you do that, you're telling the compiler that you plan on re-implemeting the method and asking it to warn you if you didn't do that.

Comment: @Coco Great to learn that, thanks. I always thought it was just a no-op.

Answer (score 5):

People often use the header as documentation for the class (and tools like AutoDoc support this). Obviously, if you're following that convention, the only sensible choice is to include redefined methods so you can explain what you've done with them. Otherwise your docs for the class are either incomplete or scattered to the four corners of the earth.

But if we're just copy-pasting the declaration, I don't personally like to redeclare methods. It's not [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) and it bloats your header unnecessarily. Less code is better code.