# how do i add or replace methods of existing objective-c classes?

Tags: objective-c, class

If I want to add one function in any class suppose Nsstring, or overwrite any method of that class how can I do this?

What is method or code for this?

Comment: Be very careful when adding methods to a class.  And **do not replace existing methods**.  *Not even if you call the original implementation*.  First class encapsulation breakage, there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if i want to add one function:

create a category:

```
@interface NSString (MONAdditions)
- (BOOL)mon_isDirectoryWritable;
@end
@implementation NSString (MONAdditions)
- (BOOL)mon_isDirectoryWritable { return random(); }
@end
```

(note: `mon_` is used here as a prefix for the selector - a very good practice for your category methods)

> or overwrite any method of that class how can i do this?

for obvious reasons, you shouldn't do this, especially for NSString. but...

you have a few options in `objc/runtime.h`. `method_exchangeImplementations` provides a simple approach:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@interface MONSwap : NSObject

/*...*/

- (void)makeCoffee;
- (void)goToSleep;

@end

@implementation MONSwap

- (void)makeCoffee
{
    self.coffeeMachine.brew;
}

- (void)goToSleep
{
    self.electricity.disable;
}

@end

void LetsPlayAnEvilTrick() {
    Class swap = [MONSwap class];
    // see also class_getClassMethod
    Method a = class_getInstanceMethod(swap, @selector(makeCoffee));
    Method b = class_getInstanceMethod(swap, @selector(goToSleep));
    method_exchangeImplementations(a, b);
}
```

Comment: One question if I may: why do you use the prefix MON? French, maybe?

Comment: @Bavarious haha, yes, it is a french derivative - where people would normally write 'MyClass' in objc example code, i write 'MONClass'. however, i am neither french nor capable of pronouncing it correctly.

Comment: we can also overwrite methods of class i am 100 % sure about this.

Comment: @Heart PAL i'm not certain of what you're asking me. however, i demonstrated an implementation in an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about subclassing in objective c check out the links

[Is subclassing in Objective-C a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844199/is-subclassing-in-objective-c-a-bad-practice)

[Objective C subclass that overrides a method in the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770642/objective-c-subclass-that-overrides-a-method-in-the-superclass)